# Python function that receives an unknown number of arguments

Tags: python, function, args

I would like to write a function that receives an unknown number of arguments, multiplies them and prints the result.

I use *args but I get the sames result if I use a tuple as the parameter.

```
# Using *args
def mult(*args):
    ans = 1
    for i in args:
        ans *= i
    print(ans)

# using a tuple
def multT(t):
    ans = 1
    for i in t:
        ans *= i
    print(ans)


mult(1,2,3,4)
multT((1,2,3,4))
```

Both functions print 24.
Is there any reason to prefer using *args and not a tuple?  If in this case it makes no difference, are there other cases when I would have to use *args and not a tuple?

Comment: Second case you have only one argument (there is no unknown number of arguments possible).That's one difference.

Comment: Example: `mult` can be called with **no arguments**, but `multT()` cannot.

Comment: Which of those two forms is going to be most convenient and/or natural to the callers of your function?  Note that it's easy to support both, as the built-in `min()` and `max()` functions do - `if len(args) == 1: args = args[0]`.

Comment: Austin - But I could send a tuple with 0 or more elements. Isn't that the same as an unknown number of arguments? The function would have to unpack the tuple just as it does with *args.

Comment: meowgoesthedog   - I can call multT with an empty tuple. In both cases I get 1.

Comment: jasonharper - Thanks! still, I would like to understand when *args is essential.

Comment: I don't know about *essential*, but have you considered how irritating it would be if you had to call `print()` with single tuple argument instead of a variable number of arguments? And, then of course, suppose you wanted to pass it a single argument that was a tuple: then you would have to do `print(((1,2,3),))`.

Comment: -BoarGules - That's a good point. Thank you.